# restart on application uninstall

Tags: android, restart

Using [setComponentEnabledSetting](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setComponentEnabledSetting%28android.content.ComponentName,int,int%29) causes the android os to restart upon uninstall. Has anyone else come across this?

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1143): *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: android.server.ServerThread
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED dat=package:com.example.foo flg=0x8000010 (has extras) } in com.android.server.NotificationManagerService$2@41b00228

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown package: com.example.foo
        at com.android.server.pm.Settings.getApplicationEnabledSettingLPr(Settings.java:2443)

Here's the code :

```
public class FooActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        enableReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        disableReceiver();
    }

    private void enableReceiver() {
        setReceiverState(PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED);
    }

    private void disableReceiver() {
        setReceiverState(PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED);
    }

    private void setReceiverState(int receiverState) {
        getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(this, FooBroadcastReceiver.class), receiverState, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }

    public static class FooBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        }
    }

}
```

the receiver in the manifest :

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.foo.FooActivity$FooBroadcastReceiver"/>
```

thanks!

Comment: FYI, this is a restart of the Android runtime, not the underlying kernel.  I wouldn't call that the OS, but some might.

Comment: Did you solve this or was it a bug in a custom rom or something?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you registered a BroadcastReceiver for the android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED Intent inside your activity, changed its state and then uninstalled the package. The crash does sound like a bug, but I'm guessing while the receiver was still registered the notification manager tried to deliver the uninstall and then crashed.

You might want to call `setReceiverState(PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT);` before you uninstall?

Comment: I tried setting <receiver enabled="false"/> and calling setComponentEnabledSetting(PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT) in onPause() but the issue still exists. Yeah, I suspect it could be a bug, but it's strange that no-one else has encountered it. There is no PACKAGE_CHANGED receiver unfortunately, but I wonder if registering one and absorbing the broadcast would resolve the situation. Thanks for your insight!

Comment: Definitely a bug in your build of Android - security rules say there is nothing you should be able to do which could cause this.  Package install/uninstall broadcasts are *not* supposed to be delivered to the triggering package.

Comment: did you find a solution around this? I have got similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and solved it by not setting the `DONT_KILL_APP` flag.

```
getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(this,
    FooBroadcastReceiver.class), receiverState, 0);
```